# Opening large ODS file takes a long time (48 min) on Windows 8.1 x64

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, odf

Tried using LibreOffice 5.0.3 rc2, 2015-11-03-nightly, and 4.4.6.3, all with the same result.

I've tried:

1. Deleting my user profile
2. Upping the Memory settings
3. Opening the file on an Ubuntu 14.04 VM (it opened immediately)
4. Opening the file on a Windows 8.1 VM (opened immediately)

Aside from those attempts, I've found nothing that might indicate why this is happening.

If you want the file, you can get it from the bugzilla page here: https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=95588

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the print spooler that was hanging up Calc. To solve, just type "services.msc" into Run... or your start menu, and stop the "Print Spooler" service.